# How to install tkinter on embeddable release of python3?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, cpython

I've created a deployment script of the embeddable release of Python3 being used portable (understand without the need of installation on windows machines without administrative rights). The python this way is barebone. It has no modules. (see the method I used [here](https://dev.to/fpim/setting-up-python-s-windows-embeddable-distribution-properly-1081))

Now we come to the problem at hand. I cannot figure out a way to install tkinter.

Different suggestions like `python -m install tk` or `tkinter`, `python-tk`, `python3-tk`, etc all fail. Actually `tk` installs some module that has nothing to do with tkinter.

I tried pulling out the tk installation from the official python installation still fail.

Does anyone have idea how could this be done?